# What is WordPress Front end and Back end Development

Tags: wordpress

I can't understand about wordpress **front end** and **back end**. Please explain about this both words.

I'm also searching on Google for this about 30 mins. But I can't find good answer.

So, I want to know about this words. Please give me an explanation about these words.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR.**

In short :

`FRONT-END` is what the normal `"Visitors"` or `"Users"` see and interact with.

`BACK-END` is the Administration Area For the `"Owners"` ( or employees / collaborators ) to manage and operate the site.

**More**

You can think of The terms `Front-end` and `Back-End` like almost any normal traditional business you already know.

For example a restaurant, where you have the `Front-area` ( main hall where the "customers" dine ), and you have the `Back area` ( kitchen, Storage, Office ) where only the Employees venture.

Or A supermarket where you have the Front area for Customers , and the Back area For Employees .

This question is not actually only for wordpress, but it will be the same for 98%, or almost each CMS,  (like drupal, joomla ) or actually any other web application.

In web applications `FRONT-END` is related to [themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), [widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets)  and everything else that a normal user or visitor to the site will see and interact with.

`Back-End` is the Administration area where the "owners" ( read : `administrators` ) of the site / app are doing their administrative work ( like uploading files, Writing posts, Managing users etc ..)

There are of course some areas where the line between Back-End and Front-End is a bit blurred, especially when dealing with [developing Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) , or more precisely functionality plugins that can actually alter the behavior for both Back-end and Front-End at the same time.

**Edit I** After comment.

Wordpress ( and other CMS ) can actually assign "administrative rights" of one grade or another to users of the site thus allowing them to Contribute ( for example Create posts, Upload media etc )

Since those "users" have different "role" they are actually restricted "administrators" - which is sometimes causing a blurry line between the terms. But since they ARE assigned rights to what is generally refereed to as "Administrative" tasks - when they are assigned access to the "Back-end" they are actually becoming de-facto "administrator" ( collaborators ) for limited areas of the site.

Semantics.

Comment: What is most often referred to as the WordPress "back end" is actually more than just the "administration area" for "owners" of the site.  It includes functionality for all registered users, which includes default roles of subscribers, authors, editors, etc. What a user has access to depends entirely upon their role and the capabilities assigned to that role.

Comment: @butlerblog . True - I will ammend. But  What a user has access to does not really depends entirely upon their role - but upon The real Administrator giving them access to it - And therefor giving them "administrative rights" - thus becoming "Administrators" of some sort.

Comment: @Nakka . No problem. Although I think the best way to easily and quickly understand this is just to [INSTALL wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) and try it . the terms become immediately clear .

Answer (score 0):

The Frontend is you wordpress Website and the backend is the website-administration page.

Answer (score 0):

In simple, front end is similar to user interface criteria and back end is similar to database and other admin criteria. And its not only for Wordpress but also for other platforms too.

Answer (score -1):

Typically the front end is where the information that determines what the end user will see is handled (html, css javascript etc.) and the backend refers to your database.